# Amazon MWS (not AWS) Data Protection Policy - Network control

Tags: security, networking, firewall

Anyone has experience regarding Network Control?

Plan to rent a dedicate server.  Does any hosting company providing any of these as part of their offer? (e.g. the dedicated server is protected by 1,2,3 by default)

1. Network segmentation
2. Virtual Private Cloud (VPC)
3. Network Access Control List (ACL)

If not, how can I implement this?

One of the hosting company I am looking at offers ASA 5505 Firewall, would this firewall implemented any of 1,2,3 above?

I plan to run the app in Docker, data is in Mysql DB.  So my plan was to install firewall on the server block all ports except 80/443 and a random port used for ssh.  And set the mysql port to a non standard port, and only allow local connection to the mysql db.  Is this secure enough?  Or I need to implement more such as 1,2,3 above?

thanks

Comment: Anyone?  Looks like this is a tough one!

Comment: any thought plz?

Comment: Have you considered hosting in AWS itself? I think easiest way to get these features is to host in AWS itself